# How to make a sitewide search in mongodb database with relevant keyword search?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, search, collections

In my mongodb project I have several collections , Below I have pointed two of them movies and directors

> Movies collections

| _id | name | gene | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 633fd724659fb41be63167cf | Game of Thrones | Adventure | 633fd424659fb41be63167cf |
| 633fd724659fb51be63167cf | Modern Family | Comedy | 633fd724659fb51be6317cf |

> Director collection

| _id | fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 633fd424659fb41be63167cf | Alan Doe |
| 633fd724659fb51be63167cf | Jhon game |

I need a sitewide search where If I type , Game, I need to get result from multiple tables and the expected result is given below

> Expected Result

| _id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 633fd724659fb41be63167cf | Game of Thrones | movie |
| 633fd724659fb51be63167cf | Jhon game | user |

Consider that the collection is large and the system should not go slow, also the search should be a relevant search, I couldn't add sample query since I am new to this sitewide search, Also do we need an extra table to manage the sitewide search?

Comment: Elasticsearch will be a better option for this use case. Otherwise, you will have to create one large collection combining all collections and create a text index on it's fields

Comment: Elasticsearch is possible in existing schema of mongodb without affecting different modules?

Comment: Elastic is a different data-store in itself. You'll have to sync the data between the two, your MongoDB modules will remain unchanged.